# Codeingiter & HMVC Unable to locate controller if in 2 level sub folder

Tags: codeigniter

If I place a controller in a 2 level sub folder "categories" will not locate it

```
application > modules > catalog > controllers > forum

application > modules > catalog > controllers > forum > categories

// unable to locate
application > modules > catalog > controllers > forum > categories > Category.php

// able to locate
application > modules > catalog > controllers > forum > Category.php
```

> **Question** is it possiable to modify MY_Router.php so can locate the folder correct and not effec any thing else.
>
> I am using codeigniter 3.1.0 and HMVC

I have looked at this [Unable to access the controller in subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838744/unable-to-access-the-controller-in-subfolder) but when enable it does not display the default_controller.

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* load the MX_Router class */
require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Router.php";

class MY_Router extends MX_Router {

    /** Locate the controller **/
    public function locate($segments)
    {
        $this->located = 0;
        $ext = $this->config->item('controller_suffix').EXT;

        /* use module route if available */
        if (isset($segments[0]) && $routes = Modules::parse_routes($segments[0], implode('/', $segments)))
        {
            $segments = $routes;
        }

        /* get the segments array elements */
        list($module, $directory, $controller) = array_pad($segments, 3, NULL);

        /* check modules */
        foreach (Modules::$locations as $location => $offset)
        {
            /* module exists? */
            if (is_dir($source = $location.$module.'/controllers/'))
            {
                $this->module = $module;
                $this->directory = $offset.$module.'/controllers/';

                /* module sub-controller exists? */
                if($directory)
                {
                    /* module sub-directory exists? */
                    if(is_dir($source.$directory.'/'))
                    {   
                        $source .= $directory.'/';
                        $this->directory .= $directory.'/';

                        /* module sub-directory controller exists? */
                        if($controller)
                        {
                            if(is_file($source.ucfirst($controller).$ext))
                            {
                                $this->located = 3;
                                return array_slice($segments, 2);
                            }
                            else $this->located = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    if(is_file($source.ucfirst($directory).$ext))
                    {
                        $this->located = 2;
                        return array_slice($segments, 1);
                    }
                    else $this->located = -1;
                }

                /* module controller exists? */
                if(is_file($source.ucfirst($module).$ext))
                {
                    $this->located = 1;
                    return $segments;
                }
            }
        }

        if( ! empty($this->directory)) return;

        /* application sub-directory controller exists? */
        if($directory)
        {
            if(is_file(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$module.'/'.ucfirst($directory).$ext))
            {
                $this->directory = $module.'/';
                return array_slice($segments, 1);
            }

            /* application sub-sub-directory controller exists? */
            if($controller)
            { 
                if(is_file(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$module.'/'.$directory.'/'.ucfirst($controller).$ext))
                {
                    $this->directory = $module.'/'.$directory.'/';
                    return array_slice($segments, 2);
                }
            }
        }

        /* application controllers sub-directory exists? */
        if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$module.'/'))
        {
            $this->directory = $module.'/';
            return array_slice($segments, 1);
        }

        /* application controller exists? */
        if (is_file(APPPATH.'controllers/'.ucfirst($module).$ext))
        {
            return $segments;
        }

        $this->located = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: application > modules is all ways first  this is hmvc

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible, but do you really really need to?

I can sort of see the sense of using...

```
application > modules > catalog > controllers > forum > Category.php
```

But I don't see the point of using...

```
application > modules > catalog > controllers > forum > categories > Category.php
```

That is going a little too deep for the sake of putting things into their own little boxes.

Personally I would make the Forum a module and have...

```
application > modules > forum > controllers > categories > Category.php
```

Comment: It is just for separation of form controllers because the categories have like a whos replied controller that I call by ajax. So was thinking be nice to have extra sub folders.